# How to register POJO factory *methods* with a Spring component?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring design problem that I've not come across before:

I have an application that manages a bunch of POJOs, I would like to register a factory for each of these POJO classes so a centralised @Component can do the management. Something like this:

```
class RouteLink implements Link {
}

class HiddenLink implements Link {
}

... lots of others

interface Loader {
    Link load(Element xml);
}

@Component
class Manager {
    private final Map<String, Loader> loaders = ...

    public void create(Element xml) {
        // Create link
        final String type = ... // from XML
        final Loader loader = loaders.get(type);
        final Link link = loader.load(xml);

        // Do something with the link we created
        ...
    }
}
```

(The links are created from an XML element, but that's not important to the question - it could be from text, or other POJOs, etc).

Now I would like to co-locate the POJO and it's associated `Loader`.  I *could* create a @Configuration class that creates a @Bean for each type but that violates the co-location and requires the developer (me!) to continually switch between source files.

Ideally I would like to do something like the following:

```
class RouteLink implements Link, Loader {
    ...

    // <--- some Spring magic here to register this as a factory
    public Link load(Element xml) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `load()` method cannot be a @Bean or a @Component because we are dealing with POJOs.  So I'm forced to create a new class just to call a single method:

```
class RouteLink ... {
    ...

    @Component
    public class RouteLinkLoader implements Loader {
        public Link load(Element xml) { .... }
    }
}
```

and the loaders are registered with the manager like this:

```
    public Manager(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        loaders = ctx.getBeansOfType(Loader.class);
    }
```

It works, sort of, but I can't help feeling I'm missing something. Is there any way of registering the load methods as components?

Notes:

- I've tried denoting the POJO classes with @Configuration but that
  then treats the class as a bean. But without that or another
  stereotype annotation any @Bean in a POJO is not scanned.
- I *could* just programatically register each POJO loader with the
  manager but that seems a bit daft when using a DI framework.
- The manager looks up the loader by *name* which is why we look them
  up from the context rather than simply auto-wiring.

I've been developing with Spring for years but seem to have a blind-spot with this design (or lack of it!)  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, what you want is to create objects that will be managed by Spring? Have you looked at Spring [BeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html)?

Comment: Yes have looked at BeanFactory - if I understand correctly it's used to create multiple beans to be be managed by the container.  Whereas I was trying to work out a way of registering POJO factories as Spring component, not bean factories. Apologies if the question is confusing, I was struggling to express the problem anyway!

Comment: I see, so what you don't want is to lose the co-location of your pojos and loader classes and still use the loaders as spring beans. Right now I can think of two ways, the 1st would be to do the reverse of your 3rd snippet and add the pojos inside the loader (assuming they could only be created trough the loader) but still a class inside a class or 2nd share the appContext with your pojos and then programmatically register the loaders in the context

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there is no magic solution to this if we want to co-locate the factory and POJO code in the same source file, basically one *has* to create a separate `@Component` to register the POJO factories.

This means we have to wrap every factory method in a class such that it can be component scanned, rather than (for example) just having a static class constant to do it, something like this:

```
class PojoClass {
    @MagicAnnotationHere
    public static final Loader LOADER = xml -> new PojoClass(...);
}
```

Can't be done, so the factory method becomes a first-class component class which means a lot more code:

```
class PojoClass {
    ...
    @Component
    class PojoLoader implements Loader {
        @Override
        public void load(Element xml) { ... }
    }
}
```

On the positive side the factories can be `@AutoWired` into the manager component as follows:

```
@Component
class Manager {
    @Autowired
    private final Map<String, Loader> loaders = new HashMap<>();
```

Spring auto-magically populates the map indexed by bean name, which is precisely what I needed to lookup the factory by name. I'll call that a score-draw!